# Limitar o fluxo de entrada a valores do tipo int

Tags: c++, tipagem, int, stream

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <limits> 

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int getVar(int num);
int getInt(int num);

int main(){

    int n;
    cout<<"Insira um inteiro. \n\n";
    getInt(n);


    return 0 ;
}
int getInt(int n){

    cin>>n;
    return getVar(n);
}

int getVar(int num){

    if(!(cin>> num &&  !num % 2 == 0)){

        cout<< num <<" Entrada nao corresponde ao tipo de variavel solicitado.\n\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        getInt(num);
    }
    else{
        cin.clear();
        cout<<"\n"<< num <<" Entrada recebida com sucesso!!! \n";
        return num;
    }
}
```

Quando digito um número que é aceito pela função, no caso um inteiro, tenho que digitá-lo duas vezes para que ele seja captado, eu gostaria que ele captasse a entrada direto na primeira tentativa.

Comment: A condição provavelmente está errada. Ela não faz sentido. Qual é o critério para que um numero deve ser aceito ou rejeitado? Explique o que o programa deve fazer. Existe alguma razão para ter duas funções auxiliares e não estar tudo no `main()`? O código está cheio de coisas desnecessárias.

Comment: bom a ideia é justamente limitar o fluxo de entrada a variaveis do tipo int

Comment: O `cin` vai garantir que é um `int`. A única coisa que dá para fazer é determinar se o que foi digitado é válido ou não. Mas aí você precisa explicar o que é considerado válido ou não.

Comment: if(!(cin>> num &&  !num % 2 == 0)) essa condição que esta fazendo o isolamento porem quando entro com um inteiro ele da erro

Comment: Eu acabei de dizer que isto não faz sentido. Explique em português qual deve ser o critério para poder te ajudar.

Comment: se e entrada for um caractere ou um tipo float ela nao deve ler com entradase for do tipo inteiro ela deve ler como entrada

Comment: Esta frase também não faz sentido. Então vamos por partes. Como vai descobrir se a a entrada é do tipo `float` se é impossível digitar um em uma variável do tipo `int`?

Comment: no caso o que essa codição qu coloquei foi tudo que for diferente de um inteiro é isolado (no caso  char )e se o modulo da divisão do que foi digitado por 2  diferente de 0 nao deve ser considerado pois é um float

Comment: Mas este é o problema, esta condição não faz o que vocês está querendo. P módulo determina se o número é par. O pedido para digitar o número de novo, não faz sentido. Se você não conseguir colocar o problema de uma forma que faça sentido, explicar o que deseja, porque o código está assim, não tem como ajudar.

Comment: mas o modulo de um divisão de um numero do tipo float nunca retorna um numero par ou retorna eu achei que essa fosse uma característica para isola a entrada de tipos float

Comment: Vou tentar postar uma solução que resolve isto do melhor forma possível, mas não tem uma solução simples e clara. Vou organizar o código também. É muita complicação para algo simples. O código atual pode dar estouro de pilha em caso extremo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, se vai pegar um número que pode ser escrito com ponto flutuante, o tipo da variável deve ser `float` e não `int`. É esquisito fazer isto, porque se quer números inteiros, peça inteiros, aí não precisa fazer nada. Mas deve ser algum exercício maluco sem sentido. Pode usar outra forma, mas é mais complexo.

Para saber se um número que pode ter parte decimal é apenas inteiro, basta comparar ele com sua parte inteira, fazendo um *cast* simples como foi feito na condição. Assim está comparando o número com decimal e o número convertido para inteiro. Se eles forem iguais é porque a conversão não perdeu nada, então já era inteiro.

Tirei todas as declarações desnecessárias e as funções que não estavam trazendo nada útil ao código, pelo contrário, estava causado problemas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float n;
    cout << "Insira um inteiro." << endl;
    while (true) {
        cin >> n;
        if (!cin.fail() && n == (int)n) break;
        cout << n << " - Entrada nao corresponde ao tipo de variavel solicitado." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }   
    cout << endl << n << " - Entrada recebida com sucesso!!!" << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QAZdoc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oadyfnlv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/ValidInt.cpp).

A verificação se `cin.fail()` foi usada para evitar que a digitação de caracteres não numéricos.

É possível simplificar um pouco mais o código se aceitar um pequena mudança de comportamento. Não poderia dar a mensagem de erro, teria que apenas pedir o número de novo.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu intendi você determina enquanto verdadeiro  capture o valor de  n se n > 0 e n é = n inteiro mas então dessa forma ele nao arredonda o numero float para int

Comment: Basicamente é isto. A verificação é dispensável para ver se um número foi digitado, conforme eu expliquei acima, coloquei para verificar se letras foram digitas, mas essa verificação é falha, não sei nem se deveria fazer isto. É que se é para verificar se o dado está certo, fica estranho aceitar letras como se fosse algo válido. De qualquer forma, vou repetir que não faz sentido fazer isto. Tem como simplificar ainda mais este código mas mudaria ligeiramente o comportamento.

Comment: e se a entrada for 0 seria um inteiro mas seria classificada como nao

Comment: É, então, esta é a falha. Se quiser tire esta parte. Mas aí e se a entrada for letra?

Comment: entendi cara lhe agradeço imensamente to começando agora então ainda ficam muita duvidas mas de cara o seu código esta bem mais limpo que o meu.mas  vc pode me dar uma ideia de como fazer esse isolamento das letras sem querer pedir demais

Comment: ou me indique algo que deve estudar para tal no momento to começando o C++ como programar 5ªed

Comment: Achei uma solução para resolver o problema do uso de caracteres não numéricos.

Comment: você questionou sobre a ideia de fazer isso é que nos exercícios que são passados no livro, sempre se fala para capturar a entrada com cin só que sempre parece que o código não fica correto pois ele não captura a entrada corretamente, daí decidi criar ramificações, tipo algo que capture só int, so float, só char e deu nisso que você viu

Comment: como é a solução?

Comment: Mas se é para "capturar" `int`, use uma variável `int` como estava fazendo, e não precisa verificar se tem ponto flutuante ou não, principalmente não precisa fazer divisão por 2 para ver se dá resto, não precisa ler o número de novo para fazer a verificação. Não faça o que a linguagem já faz por você. Você está jogando códigos aleatórios. Se não entender o que está fazendo, não conseguirá produzir nada que seja útil e que seja **certo** que funciona. A solução está na resposta.